# jQuery data $(...).data('foo') sometimes returning undefined in Backbone app

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views, custom-data-attribute

Running into a weird bug – so I have an attribute defined as 'data-tagtype' on my `button` elems in my HTML. When a user clicks on a button, the following method gets called:

```
onClickTag: function(e) {
  if (!this.playerLoaded) {
    return false;
  }
  var type = $(e.target).data('tagtype');
  var seconds = this.getCurrentTime();
  console.log(type);
  if (type) {
    this.model.addTag({
      type: type,
      seconds: seconds
    });
  }
},
```

This works *most* of the time, but for some reason sometimes `type` is undefined for (seemingly) random elements. The corresponding HTML is here:

```
<button id="tag-love" class="tagger disabled" data-tagtype="love"><i class="fa fa-heart fa-fw"></i></button>
<button id="tag-important" class="tagger disabled" data-tagtype="important"><i class="fa fa-exclamation fa-fw"></i> Important</button>
<button id="tag-more" class="tagger disabled" data-tagtype="more"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h fa-fw"></i> More</button>
<button id="tag-confused" class="tagger disabled" data-tagtype="confused"><i class="fa fa-question fa-fw"></i> Confused</button>
```

It's weird because there doesn't seem to be a pattern with respect to which ones return undefined when. Sometimes all of them work and sometimes one of them returns undefined for a couple of seconds, but then if I keep clicking it returns the proper value.

The View is definitely rendered/loaded into the DOM before any of these methods get called.

Any ideas? Does Backbone do something maybe?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that Backbone views use event delegation for their event handling. That means that `e.target` will be the the element that is clicked rather than the element that is responding to the event. If you click on the `<i>`, `e.target` will be that `<i>` but if you click on the text, `e.target` will be the `<button>`; the `<i>` doesn't have the data attribute you're looking for but the `<button>` does. That means that sometimes `$(e.target).data('tagtype')` will be `undefined`.

You can see this behavior in a simple example:

```
<div id="x">
    <button type="button" data-tagtype="love"><i>icon</i> text</button>
</div>
```

and a minimal view:

```
var V = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#x',
    events: {
        'click button': 'clicked'
    },
    clicked: function(ev) {
        console.log(
            $(ev.target).data('tagtype'),
            $(ev.currentTarget).data('tagtype')
        );
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/pe77p/

If you click on `<i>icon</i>`, you'll get `undefined love` in the console but if you click on the `text`, you'll get `love love` in the console.

That little demo also contains the solution: use `e.currentTarget` instead of `e.target`.